# Is there a way solve 'SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized' with .replace()?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to replace a specific substring in the keys of a dictionary with this code:

```py
# **kwargs is taken from a function, I'm just showing the content of it 
name = 'foobar'
kwargs = {'__async': 'none', 'in_width': 'foo'}

part_of_key_to_replace = {'__': '', '_': '-'}
all_attr = f"<{name} ", *(f"  {key.replace((key, value) for key, value in part_of_key_to_replace.items())}='{value}'" for key, value in kwargs.items()), ">"

def join_attr(tup):      # Joins the tuple to form a string
    string = ''
    for item in tup:
        string = string + item
        string = string.replace('  ', ' ')
    return string

print(join_attr(all_attr))
```

I expected the output to be:

```py
<foobar asnync='none' in-width='foo' >
```

It instead gives a SyntaxError:

```py
  File "<fstring>", line 47
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized
```

I've looked up at other solutions, but they're specific to an old version of Django, which I'm not working with here.

How do I rectify this? Is there a more efficient way to do this?
I'm guessing there's an issue with the `*(f"...")` part.
Thanks.

Comment: What was `key.replace(key, value for key, value in key_to_replace.items())` supposed to mean? Were you trying to replace all keys with the corresponding values? That's not how `str.replace` works, plus even if `str.replace` had such functionality, the syntax wouldn't look like that.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I was trying to replace a specific part of each key with `part_of_key_to_replace`

Comment: You cannot make several substitutions with one call to `replace`. You need a `for` loop, not list comprehension.

Comment: @DYZ the issue is I need to print all the keys and the values in one line like    
```
key1=value1 key2=value2
```
 and so on...

Comment: Why is that an issue? Build the string in a loop and print it.